# how to read boolean value using angular and php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I'm new to Angular and PHP.  I'm trying to modify tutorial http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/ajax-with-angular-and-php.  I want the second value to be a checkbox and to read its value using Angular and PHP.  The problem I experience now is that the checkbox reads value when it is clicked, but fails to input 0 (that is false) when unchecked.  I tried to convert boolean to integer from PHP, but it didn't help.  My code is below (changes to original tutorial):

index.html

```
<div>
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="newPhone">
</div>
```

post.php

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$connect = connect();

// Add the new data to the database.
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($postdata);
if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata))
{
    $request     = json_decode($postdata);

    $newName  = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/','',$request->newName);
    //old code to get number
    //$newPhone = preg_replace('/[^0-9 ]/','',$request->newPhone);
    //new code to get boolean converted to int
    $newPhone = (int)$request->newPhone;

    if($newName  == '' || $newPhone == '') return;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `people`(`name`, `phone`) VALUES ('$newName','$newPhone')";

    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
}
exit;
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` to break `IF` condition or `FOR` loops.

`return` is used in case of `functions`

```
if($newName  == '' || $newPhone == '') break;
```

Another clean approach will be to reverse your condition i.e. update only if both the values are present.

```
if(!empty($newName) && !empty($newPhone))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `people`(`name`, `phone`) VALUES ('$newName','$newPhone')";

    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
}
```

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) will check for `blank` and `null` values.

**Update**

To insert blank or 0 value in case user doesn't select a value, remove condition that checks on blank values and do it as under.

```
if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata))
{
    $request     = json_decode($postdata);

    $newName  = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/','',$request->newName);

    // Assign blank value in case its empty
    $newName = !empty($newName) ? $newName: '';

    $newPhone = (int)$request->newPhone;

    // Assign blank value in case its empty
    $newPhone = !empty($newPhone) ? $newPhone : '';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `people`(`name`, `phone`) VALUES ('$newName','$newPhone')";

    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've tried both approaches and none is doing what I wanted.  I wanted to have 0, null or false inserted into the database when user doesn't click the checkbox (i.e. has no phone).

Comment: I tried something like this, but it doesn't work either :$newPhone = (int)$request->newPhone;
 if(!empty($newName) && ($newPhone == 0)){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `people`(`name`, `phone`) VALUES ('$newName', 0)";

  mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
 }

Comment: I've tried your updated post, but it doesn't work.  It still processes the checked value, but not empty or unchecked values:(

Comment: Then there is issue with how you are getting values of checkbox.

Comment: Ok I'll check it out.